# Avoid line break when using span tag

Tags: javascript, html, function, innerhtml

I've created an HTML script that allows the user to update keywords in a block of text, then copy that text to their clipboard. The text should display like this:

```html
{
  "key1":"value1",
  "key2":"value2",
  "key3":"value3"
}
```

But because of the "span" tags, the formatting is completely off (run the code below to see what I mean). I believe span is adding a line break before and after the text it is covering.

Here is my code:

```html
<p>Enter value 1</p>
<input type="text" id="myText1" value="1st value">
<br>
<p>Enter value 2</p>
<input type="text" id="myText2" value="2nd value">
<br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Update text block</button>
<br>
<br>
<pre style="color: #000; background: #cccccc; padding:10px; display: inline-flex" id="TextToCopy">
{
  "key1":"<span id="var1">value1</span>",
  "key2":"<span id="var2">value2</span>",
  "key3":"value3"
}</pre>
<button style="display: grid" onclick="copyToClipboard()">Click to Copy</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText1").value;
  document.getElementById("var1").innerHTML = x;
  var y = document.getElementById("myText2").value;
  document.getElementById("var2").innerHTML = y;
}
</script>

 <script>
function copyToClipboard() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("TextToCopy");
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.innerText);
}
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `display: inline-flex;` property, and it should work:

```
<pre style="color: #000; background: #cccccc; padding:10px;" id="TextToCopy">
{
  "key1":"<span id="var1">value1</span>",
  "key2":"<span id="var2">value2</span>",
  "key3":"value3"
}</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS style to remove the white space before and after the text:

```
<pre style="color: #000; background: #cccccc; padding:10px; display: inline-flex; white-space: pre-wrap;" id="TextToCopy">
{
  "key1":"<span id="var1">value1</span>",
  "key2":"<span id="var2">value2</span>",
  "key3":"value3"
}</pre>
```

The `white-space: pre-wrap;` style will preserve any line breaks in the text, while still preventing the text from breaking to a new line when the text is too wide to fit the container.

Comment: In this particular situation, I don't have access to using CSS. It has to be pure inline HTML

Answer (score 1):

It can be done without span or ids

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <p>Enter value 1</p>
      <input type="text" id="myText1" value="1st value">
      <br>
      <p>Enter value 2</p>
      <input type="text" id="myText2" value="2nd value">
      <br>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Update text block</button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <pre style="color: #000; background: #cccccc; padding:10px; display: inline-flex" id="TextToCopy">
</pre>
      <button style="display: grid" onclick="copyToClipboard()">Click to Copy</button>
      <script>
         function myFunction() {
           var x = document.getElementById("myText1").value;
           var y = document.getElementById("myText2").value;
           document.getElementById("TextToCopy").innerHTML =
           
           `
         {
            "key1":"${x}",
            "key2":"${y}",
            "key3":"value3"
         }
           `;
         }
      </script>
      <script>
         function copyToClipboard() {
           var copyText = document.getElementById("TextToCopy");
           navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.innerText);
         }
      </script> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In my situation, I need to display the text before the button is pushed. Thank you though for your comment